# Cant import sql file to CloudPanel VPS server via SSH

Tags: mysql, linux, ssh, putty, vps

I have uploaded the database file `dbz.sql` to the `backups` folder. You can see the file name in the commands and results provided below.

My objective is to import the `dbz.sql` file into my existing database named 'dbzcrm' on this VPS server.

I ran the following command to import the file: `clpctl db:import --databaseName=dbzcrm --file=dbz.sql`. The command executed without any errors, but I cannot see the SQL file imported into the `dbzcrm` database.

I have been working on this for almost 12 hours. Can you help me understand why the import is not working?

SSH login details:

- IP Address: 154.49.243.219
- Username: dbzcrmssh
- Password:

System information:

- Operating System: Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
- Kernel version: 5.15.0-1034-kvm x86_64

Directory structure:

```
/home/dbzcrmssh
|-- backups
|-- htdocs
|-- logs
|-- tmp
```

Steps performed:

1. Accessed the `tmp` directory: `cd /home/dbzcrmssh/tmp`
2. Verified the contents of the directory: `ls`
3. Navigated to the `backups` directory: `cd /home/dbzcrmssh/backups`
4. Checked the contents of the `backups` directory: `ls`
5. Accessed the `databases` directory: `cd /home/dbzcrmssh/backups/databases`
6. Listed the contents of the `databases` directory: `ls`
7. Entered the `dbzcrm` directory: `cd /home/dbzcrmssh/backups/databases/dbzcrm`
8. Viewed the contents of the `dbzcrm` directory: `ls`
9. Navigated to the `2023-07-02` directory: `cd /home/dbzcrmssh/backups/databases/dbzcrm/2023-07-02`
10. Checked the contents of the `2023-07-02` directory: `ls`
11. Ran the import command to import `dbz.sql` into the `dbzcrm` database: `clpctl db:import --databaseName=dbzcrm --file=dbz.sql`

Please provide assistance in understanding why the SQL file is not being imported into the `dbzcrm` database despite running the import command.

Here is the project Link: https://www.digitalbuzzindia.com/dbz/

I also tried executing the sql file to my local server. And it works perfectly. You can access the file placed in backups folder for confirmation.

Commands Showing file in the folder: https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3GNa.png